# Error with file to bring magento site to local

Tags: magento2.3, php

I am working on a magento site that I brought to local. I have already created my virtualhost, but when I run my code I get the following error.

```
Warning: require(C:\xampp7.3\htdocs\euro\vendor\composer/../magento2translations/language_es_es/registration.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp7.3\htdocs\euro\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 75

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp7.3\htdocs\euro\vendor\composer/../magento2translations/language_es_es/registration.php' (include_path='C:\xampp7.3\htdocs\euro\vendor/magento/zendframework1/library;C:\xampp7.3\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp7.3\htdocs\euro\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 75
```

Comment: Did you run `bin/magento setup:upgrade`?

Answer (score 0):

Run `composer dump-autoload` then run `bin/magento setup:upgrade`